# selenium+python+firefox+cron неправильно работает скрипт

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, crontab

Столкнулся с проблемой.
Имею скрипт на pythone, который запускает firefox выполняет некие действия и т.д.
При запуске его из ssh консоли он отрабатывает как положено, а при запуске из crontab работает некорректно. Причем ошибок по коду и модулям нет, но визуально сайт выдает как-будто версию для другого языка. Конкретно касается yandex smart capcha - текст на ней не русский становится.
Пробовал заголовки добавлять в firefox - не помогает.
Есть ли способ, чтобы cron запускал скрипт с полной эмуляцией запуска из ssh?

Comment: А можете код программы приложить?